# create regex pattern for a string

Tags: c#, regex

I have to create regex for file name patterns, the program I am building in c# sharp would check against the pattern if the file name matches the regex :

```
ATNMR20111101-BATCH2240_20111113-091322.txt 
DGTHLK826908_20111113-091413.txt  
2011-12-01_DGTVUE_TUR_20111208-121517.txt 
BVVHUO_DAILY_YOU_092011_20111215-022931.txt
```

how do I create a pattern for these, any help is appreciated.

Comment: You don't explain exactly what pattern you want to match.

Comment: Could you be more specific? One possible answer - `.+\.txt`...

Comment: I need all because I have so many different text files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you want to match/capture:

```
[A-Z0-9-_]+_\d+-\d{6}\.txt
```

this would help you parse:

```
BVVHUO_DAILY_YOU_092011 _ 20111215 - 022931 .txt
[      this part      ]   [ this ]   [this]
      [A-Z0-9-_]+            \d+       \d{6}
```

that's just from me trying to determine a pattern across your strings

Comment: Thanks for the help Joe. building regex for different file formats. (?:[a-z][a-z0-9_]*)-BATCH\d+_\d+-\d+\.(?:[a-z][a-z]+) for type "SUXX20111101-BATCH2240_20111113-091322.txt"

Comment: some regex flavors will require that the "-" in a character class appear as the first character, else it is confused with a range specifier.  So change [A-Z0-9-_] to [-A-Z0-9_]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a starting point and a good testing tool: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2vjla

You will need to be more specific if you expect more detailed answers.